# Why is mutate(across)) converting a factor to an integer?

Tags: r, dplyr, integer

I have a dataset that contains NaN values that I would like to change to NA. I came up with the following solution. However, one unintended side effect is that it changes columns that are factors into integers. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(x1 = factor(c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                              "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")),
                x2 = c(seq(1,20,1)),
                x3 = c(seq(21,40,1)))

x[12,1] <- NA
x[16,2] <- NA
x[3,3] <- NA

str(x)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ x2: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x3: num  21 22 NaN 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...


x <- x %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), ~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .)))

str(x)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ x2: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x3: num  21 22 NA 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for NaN values. (rather than just NA values), it probably makes sense to only look at numeric columns. And also `if_else` sometimes needs to used the "typed" version of the NA value so it can properly combine all values into the correct vector type. This should work

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric), ~if_else(is.nan(.), NA_real_, .)))
```

Note that this weird NA quirk [is fixed in the current dev version](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/NEWS.md#dplyr-development-version) ([see this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6243)) so you should be able to use just NA in the main package soon.

Comment: Ah of course. Nan should only be in numeric columns. Makes perfect sense!